# Port ScaleTransform.Changed event in from WPF to Silverlight

Tags: wpf, silverlight, scaletransform

In WPF, the ScaleTransform has an event called Changed which raises whenever the scale X/Y is changed. But this event does not exist in Silverlight.

Is there any way we can implement the same thing in Silverlight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workaround for this. Actually, we can hook CompositionTarget.Rendering event when the storyboard begins. After the storyboard is completed, we need unhook the event too to save the performance. In the Rendering event, we can get the dynamical value of the ScaleTransform's scale x/y and it solves my issue. Hope it helps if you have the same requirement.